# Are all US fighter/combat aircraft constantly armed, even just in training?

Tags: us-air-force

I remember hearing once upon a time that all US fighter/combat aircraft constantly armed, even just in training. If I recall correctly, it's because the pilots need to be ready at a moment's notice.

Is this true?

Comment: No, for example the F-15 and F-16's are often flown for airshows/sporting events without being armed. Some may require ballast in the place of the arms though, I think the A-10 requires it.

Comment: thank you. i remember hearing that long ago and my wandering mind gets the best of me

Comment: @Ron Beyer: If a plane requires ballast, what happens in combat after it has expended all its munitions?

Comment: I meant if the cannon was removed.

Comment: Not only is the answer no, but this was a specific issue during the 9/11 response where some of the responding fighters were unarmed.

Comment: Bit late but see this story: https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/f-16-pilot-was-ready-to-give-her-life-on-sept-11/2015/09/06/7c8cddbc-d8ce-11e0-9dca-a4d231dfde50_story.html

Comment: No, if by "armed" you mean "capable of expending ordinance". ALl fighters with guns always have the guns, (it's not possible or necessary  to remove them for flights when they are not needed) and, for weight and balance issues, often they still carry gun ammunition, but unless there is a real or training requirement to fire the gun, it is will be safetied from the gun bay where the aircrew is not able to fire it.

Answer (score 8):

As a general rule, unless you are going to use ordnance e.g. training, alert status, or war, you are not going to have it loaded on the jet.  It's just another risk to personnel or equipment out on the line, in hangars, etc.  Aircraft returning with live ordnance are disarmed and unloaded after shutdown and the weapons defused and returned to the bomb farms on base or magazines aboard ship.